# How do I write Routing Chains for a Subdomain in Zend Framework in a routing INI file?

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, subdomain, ini

I am trying to create a subdomain using the Zend Router, and then for each section under a subdomain, such as subdomain.site.com/section/ I am creating another route and then trying to chain it to the subdomain route. but I don't know how.  I have read all the documentation I could find and all the forums, but it leads me to figure it out on my own. So far, my attempts just get me this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to
>   Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite::addRoute() must implement interface
>   Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Interface, null given, called in
>   /var/local/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Router/Rewrite.php on line 155
>   and defined in
>   /var/local/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Router/Rewrite.php on line 93

with the following code:

```
routes.b2b.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
routes.b2b.route = "sales.sitename.com"
routes.b2b.defaults.module = b2b
routes.b2b.defaults.controller = index
routes.b2b.defaults.action = index

routes.b2b_signup.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.b2b_signup.route = "/signup"
routes.b2b_signup.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.b2b_signup.defaults.action   = "signup"

routes.b2b_login.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain"
routes.b2b_login.chain = b2b_signup
```

I cannot find an example of how to do chaining this with an INI file anywhere on the net. The entire application is written in an INI for the routing config, so I can't switch it over to an array based config (or XML for that matter), in which 100% of the examples on the internet are in.

If I could do it in array form, I could just say this:

```
$hostnameRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
    'sales.sitename.com',
    array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'module'     => 'b2b',
        'action'     => 'index'
    )
);

$hostnameRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static(
    '/signup',
    array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'module'     => 'b2b',
        'action'     => 'signup'
    )
);
    $chainedRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Chain();
    $chainedRoute->chain($b2b_signup)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do the above in an INI file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's basically what you want, in INI format:

```
routes.b2b.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
routes.b2b.route = "sales.sitename.com"
; you could specify a default module (or anything) to use for the whole 
; route chain here, like so: 
; routes.b2b.defaults.module = "default"

routes.b2b.chains.signup.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.b2b.chains.signup.route = "/signup"
routes.b2b.chains.signup.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.b2b.chains.signup.defaults.action = "signup"

routes.b2b.chains.anotherroute.route = "/something/:foo" ; etc, etc.
routes.b2b.chains.anotherroute.defaults.action = "foo"
routes.b2b.chains.anotherroute.defaults.controller = "index"
routes.b2b.chains.anotherroute.defaults.foo = "bar"
routes.b2b.chains.anotherroute.reqs.foo = '[a-z]+'
```

This will give you the following routes: `b2b-signup`, and `b2b-anotherroute`.

Here's some important notes on route chaining:

When chaining routes together, the parameters of the outer route have a higher priority than the parameters of the inner route. Thus if you define a controller in the outer and in the inner route, the controller of the outer route will be selected.

Parent / child chained route names are always concatenated with a dash! So, like in the example above, `b2b.chains.signup` becomes a route named `b2b-signup` (which you can use for URL assembly, etc).

You can keep chaining! Chains of chains can have chains.

Children of chained routes do not work with wildcards. See [#ZF-6654](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6654). Here's [blog post](http://www.noginn.com/2009/02/04/revisiting-hostname-routing-with-the-zend-framework/) that talks about why that may not be a big deal.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. You have really helped me out since I just started working with the ZF a few months back and there is literally nothing on the internet that I could find (I guess until this post) that described how to do this in the INI. Thank you very much!
Can you recommend any good books for ZF?

Comment: No, sadly. I've never read any of the books (or book?) about the Zend Framework. That said, Rob Allen's Zend Framework in Action http://www.zendframeworkinaction.com/ is supposed to be good. However, due to the fast pace in which development happens with ZF, books get outdated fast; very fast. For example, nothing about route chains, Zend_Application, or Zend_Tool would be in that book.

Comment: "You can keep chaining! Chains of chains can have chains."

I was wondering which one is the correct way:
 1. routes.b2b.chains.anotherroute.chains.yetanotherroute...
 2. routes.anotherroute.chains.yetanotherroute...

Comment: I believe your first example would be the correct one, Kenji.