# Subdomain Routing Rules (using chaining) Broke after upgrading to Zend Framework 1.9.5, but only for the root, not pages

Tags: zend-framework, routes, subdomain, chaining

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052614/how-do-i-write-routing-chains-for-a-subdomain-in-zend-framework-in-a-routing-ini) months ago on how to write chaining rules in an `app.ini` format. The answer to this question worked wonderfully! Now, however, I have upgraded to the latest version of the Zend Framework 1.9.5 (I needed to upgrade for another issue) and now my subdomains no longer work!

To clarify, if I visit `subdomain.domain.com`, it does not recognize my rule.
However, if I visit `subdomain.domain.com/somepage/` it **does** recognize my routing rule.

Here is my code:

```
;; the following is apparently being ignored, and does not work
routes.manager.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname"
routes.manager.route = "manager.sitename.com"
routes.manager.defaults.module = "manager"

;; this is not being ignored and works!
routes.manager.chains.settings.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.manager.chains.settings.route = "/settings"
routes.manager.chains.settings.defaults.controller = "manager"
routes.manager.chains.settings.defaults.action  = "settings"
```

So for example, if I go to `manager.sitename.com`, it just redirects to my default index and controller (does not access the module, `$this->getRequest()->getModuleName()` is blank).
However, if I go to `manager.sitename.com/settings`, the page comes up!  This `app.ini` configuration works fine in ZF 1.7.8, But now since I upgraded to 1.9.5, it no longer works.

I have tried adding `routes.manager.defaults.controller = "manager"` and `routes.manager.defaults.action = 'index"` to my configuration as well, but this didn't work.

There is not much out there on the internet with chaining and `app.ini` dealing with Zend Framework. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. The problem, first off, is due to a bug in the Zend Framework routing rules, causing an empty static route (blank string) to never match. This is why `sub.example.com/hello.php` will work, but not `sub.example.com`.

There is a patch for this, and it works perfectly.

Please go [here](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7848) to read more about this issue and get the patch. Hopefully they integrate this patch into the trunk sometime soon.